# web-based proxy with Flash,Silverlight and Applets

Tags: php, javascript, proxy

I'm writing a php-based proxy server with support of various protocols and stuff and I've reached a level where I need to implement the support of Flash, AJAX, Silverlight and Java applets.

Technically I know that these browser plugins use browsers' infrastructures to establish connections but I thought that there might be some creative solutions out there for this very purpose.

So here is my questions:

- Is there a way to implement support of **`Flash`** in a web-based proxy?
- Is there a way to implement support of **`Silverlight`** in a web-based proxy?
- Is there a way to implement support of **`Java applets`** in a web-based proxy?
- Is there a way to implement support of **`AJAX calls`** in a web-based proxy?

And better I'd say:

- Is there any way to create a sand-boxed environment for a web-application and capture all it's out-going connections just via a web-proxy and proxify them?

Comment: AJAX calls are just http requests. The only 'special' thing about them is that they're done in the background instead of forcing a full blown page reload.

Comment: AJAX calls are at the client-end. To your proxy, they'll look no different from normal webrequests.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon So you mean that I can proxify them by processing the fetched javascript files, right?

Comment: If you have a proxy-server that can service HTTP requests, you are all set for AJAX as well. It is a proxy server right? You receive requests, fetch response, hand it over to client. or do you mean something else?

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon I almost forgot about the fact that all AJAX calls must be relative to my proxy since they're not cross-domain except the case that the AJAX's target URL has been hard-coded in the script with absolute path to it's target domain.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon It's simple, AJAX calls are not cross-domain, right? so the AJAX call's target url must be coded relative. like `/content.php` but what if somehow, someone, hard-code the call's url like this: `http://example.com/content.php`? these urls must be converted to their relative equivalents. got it? :D

Comment: Ohkay.. Now I get what you are trying to do :D